# Azure Lab Services: Multiple VM in template?

Tags: azure-lab-services

How can I have more than one VM in a Azure Lab Services Lab?
Example: 
1 x Windows Server OS VM
1 x Windows 10 OS VM
Shared network connection between the devices?

I just don't see any options for this setup? Why would they have something called lab services if you can't build out a whole lab?

Answer (score 0):

Azure Lab Services allows for a single template VM to be created and for a set number of virtual machines to be generated from this template - so the scenario you have outlined isn't directly supported; however, you could build your own virtual lab within the template VM using Hyper-V (assuming you are running an instance of Microsoft Windows). Note that Medium-sized VM instances (and above) in Azure Lab Services includes support for nested virtualisation.